# Disable DoubleTapGesture Zoom out on MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have observed `MKMapView` zoom-out on Double tap gesture, I didn't find any way to disable it. I tried to add own Double Tap Gesture to catch Double tap action but it still zoom out. Any thought?

Comment: Do you want to disable zoom completely? Or only on double-tap? If only on double-tap, why?

Comment: Only double tap. Actually when Zoom to Max zoom level and its Zoom level reduces on Double tap. Ideally in standard iOS Map app, it is not happening.

Comment: This is a little confusing, and may be due to "wording". With a default `MKMapView`, double-tap will ***zoom in*** -- that is, if you're currently looking at a whole country, each double tap will "get closer to the ground" until you're at maximum zoom, so you only see one road, for example. After that, double-tapping doesn't do anything. Are you experiencing something different? Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Hey, I agree with behaviour your mentioning, but works weird, It was expected. I am sharing sample. Let me if it justifies my issue. I appreciate you response. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud06uzynxfflkbi/MapSample.zip?dl=0

Comment: Looking at the example app you posted, I don't see it working "weird." As far as I can tell, double-tap does the same thing as Apple Maps? However, if you***really*** want to disable double-tap, I'm posting an answer with one approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to disable or change double-tap behavior with `MKMapView`.

But, if you really want to do so, one approach would be to find and remove the double-tap gesture recognizer from the `MKMapView` object.

In the project you shared, you could do that in `makeUIView` in your `UIMapView` class:

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UIMapView>) -> UIViewType {
    self.configureView(mapView, context: context)
    setRegion(to: palce)
    
    if let v = mapView.subviews.first,
       let ga1 = v.gestureRecognizers
    {
        let ga2: [UITapGestureRecognizer] = ga1.compactMap { $0 as? UITapGestureRecognizer } .filter { ($0.numberOfTapsRequired == 2) }
        for g in ga2 {
            v.removeGestureRecognizer(g)
        }
    }

    return mapView
}
```

I wouldn't necessarily suggest that you do so, however.

- Apple may change the `MKMapView` object in the future, which could then break this.
- User's tend to prefer that *common UI elements* behave in expected ways.

Personally, I get rather annoyed when using an app and the developer has changed standard functionality of UI elements. For example, if I see a table view row with a disclosure indicator (the right-arrow / chevron), I expect that tapping the row will "push" to another screen related to that row. I've seen apps that do **not** follow that pattern, and it just gets confusing.

Comment: Thanks mate, I agree with you we must not play with standard behaviour, there is high chance of breaking it in near future. Your way would work for sure, I come across same work around but I was thinking there might be some change MKMapView behaviour<some API>.  Thank You again for coming up solution and very very clear explanation